hover button bubble effect and gradient
There is a layout with logic for the button. When you hover over the button, the text should move to the left and a line in the circle should appear. There is also a problem with applying a gradient for two elements (text and arrow). I tried to design this button. But my code is not flexible. If I add more text the button breaks. Maybe someone has seen a similar case or can tell me how to fix it.


.button {
  color: #1C1624;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 185px;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  transition: opacity .3s;
  z-index: 1;
  &:hover {
    color: #1C1624;
    text-decoration: none;
    .button__label {
      width: 85%;
      &:before {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    .button__arrow {
      &:before {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      svg {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }
  &:active {
    .button__label {
      &:before {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      &:after {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    .button__arrow {
      &:before {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      &:after {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }
  &__label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: all .3s linear;
    &:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border-radius: inherit;
      opacity: 0;
      background: linear-gradient(91.75deg, #00F575 9.9%, #72BBCA 100%);
      transition: all .3s linear;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border-radius: inherit;
      opacity: 1;
      background: $colorAccent;
      z-index: -2;
    }
  }
  &__arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: transparent;
    transition: all .3s linear;
    z-index: 1;
    &:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border-radius: inherit;
      opacity: 0;
      background: linear-gradient(91.75deg, #72BBCA 50%, #B19BF9 100%);
      z-index: -1;
    }
    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border-radius: inherit;
      opacity: 1;
      background: $colorAccent;
      z-index: -2;
    }
    svg {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all .3s linear;
    }
  }
}
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <span class="button__label">
    START
  </span>
  <div class="button__arrow">
    <svg width="18" height="16" viewBox="0 0 18 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8.57107 0.749983L15.6421 7.82105M15.6421 7.82105L8.57107 14.8921M15.6421 7.82105L0 7.82104" stroke="#1C1624" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
  </div>
</a>



Image showing desired effect:


I made a snippet of what you posted but it does not seem to come anywhere near what you describe when executed.  FWIW this is a LOT of CSS for what is described as a simple thing.

I finally found a solution.
https://codepen.io/masterluiji19/pen/mdYbwEE?editors=1100
Perhaps there is a simpler solution. I'll be glad to see you.

I am curious, your  image shows two buttons that appear to have the "hover" effect active.  Does that mean you want some sort of "combined" hover or is/are there some missing details on the requirement not visible here or in the linked code?

The current layout shows the state of the button: button, hover, active, disable.
